# Local storage on checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.2

Where and why checkout-data section from local storage object cleaned after added product to cart?

**Before:**

```
{
  "checkout-data": {
    "selectedShippingAddress": null,
    "shippingAddressFromData": {
      "company": "",
      "telephone": "",
      "firstname": "Tetwe",
      "lastname": "twetwet",
      "street": {
        "0": "twetew",
        "1": "",
        "2": ""
      },
      "city": "213123",
      "postcode": "123123",
      "country_id": "DE",
      "region": ""
    },
    "newCustomerShippingAddress": null,
    "selectedShippingRate": null,
    "selectedPaymentMethod": null,
    "selectedBillingAddress": null,
    "billingAddressFromData": null,
    "newCustomerBillingAddress": null,
    "validatedEmailValue": "tesdasd@asd.ru",
    "inputFieldEmailValue": "tesdasd@asd.ru"
  }
}
```

**After added product to cart and reload checkout page:**

```
{
  "checkout-data":{
    "selectedShippingAddress":null,
    "shippingAddressFromData": null,
    "newCustomerShippingAddress":null,
    "selectedShippingRate":null,
    "selectedPaymentMethod":null,
    "selectedBillingAddress":null,
    "billingAddressFromData":null,
    "newCustomerBillingAddress":null
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find solutions?

Comment: Didn't, but admittedly the problem are loss the user session

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237483/mage-cache-storage-clean-after-reload-page-magento-2-1-checkout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was decided at Magento 2.3
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12362