# mage-cache-storage clean after reload page magento 2.1 checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, session

I input some information at the checkout. It write in mage-cache-storage.[image] When I reload checkout page mage-cache-storage are clearing. Why is this happening? How I can fix it? 
Thanks in advance.

I found core file for testing. Path is: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/frontend/sections.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="checkout/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/delete">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/index/index">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/updatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/updateItemOptions">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/couponPost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/estimatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/cart/estimateUpdatePost">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/onepage/saveOrder">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="last-ordered-items"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/sidebar/removeItem">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/payment-information">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="last-ordered-items"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/guest-carts/*/payment-information">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/guest-carts/*/selected-payment-method">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/selected-payment-method">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

And added here

```
<action name="checkout/*">
 <section name="checkout-data"/>
</action>
```

Comment: Please share how you trying to save those data in browser storage

Comment: @kunj I added in etc/section.xml <action name="checkout/*"> <section name="checkout-data"/> </action>

Comment: Which data wants to reload you can do by sections.xml

Comment: @PrinceYadav all shipping address and email. But I add <action name="checkout/*"> <section name="checkout-data"/> </action>, but it doesn't work

Comment: can you edit on sample code

Comment: @PrinceYadav I was adding question

Answer (score 4):

> Magento assumes that customer's private data is changed when a
>   customer sends some state modification request (POST, PUT, DELETE). To
>   minimize the load on server, developers should specify which action
>   (or request) updates which customer data section in etc/section.xml.
>
> ```
> <action name="checkout/cart/add">
>     <section name="cart"/>
> </action>
> ```

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/143381/69

Also further reading:

- [Magento 2: Syncing Backend and Frontend State/Cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93398/magento-2-syncing-backend-and-frontend-state-cache)

Comment: I added <action name="checkout/*">
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>, but it doesn't work